# Why is the request not working correctly when using BelongsToMany Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-8

I have 2 models in my app, 'Subject' & 'Professor' (each Subject belongs to many Professors).

I made the many-to-many relation between two model using belongsToMany(). belongsToMany() doesn't work.

I'm trying to get data like this:

```
$subjects = Subject::with(["professors"])->whereHas("professors", function ($q){ $q->where("id", \request("professor_id")); })->get();
```

Error:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `subjects` where exists (select * from `professors` inner join `subjects_of_professor` on `professors`.`id` = `subjects_of_professor`.`professor_id` where `subjects`.`id` = `subjects_of_professor`.`subject_id` and `id` = 39))",
```

Does anyone know where did I make a mistake?

Here's the code to Models:

```
class Subject extends Model
{
    public function professors(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Professor::class, "subjects_of_professor");
    }
}

class Professor extends Model
{
    public function subjects(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class, "subjects_of_professor");
    }
}
```

And here is my database structure:

```
subjects: 
   id
   title

subjects_of_professor:
   id
   subject_id
   professor_id

professors:
   id
   name
   description
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm found mistake, i was needed to add table in my code, when i trying to get data:

```
$subjects = Subject::whereHas("professors", function ($q){ $q->where("professors.id", \request("professor_id")); })->get();
```